# How to calculate a infinite series divided by infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am confused in calculating this limit, is it infinite?
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}
$$

Here is where I find this question:

when
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
    0,x<\pi\\
    \frac{(-1)^k}{k},x\in[k\pi,(k+1)\pi),k\in\mathbb{Z}^+
\end{cases}
$$

the limit

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}f(x)\sin(nx)dx\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int^{(k+1)\pi}_{k\pi}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\sin(nx)dx\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\frac{1}{n}(\cos(nk\pi)-\cos(n(k+1)\pi))
\end{aligned}
$$

When $n$ is even, the limits is zero.

But when $n$ is odd, the limit equals to

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}2(-1)^k
$$

which equals to

$$
2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}
$$

Comment: Think about the value for a fixed $n$. For example what if $n=1$? $n=2$?

Comment: $\sum\limits^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}$ is infinite. Dividing this by a finite positive number does not change this

Comment: But $n$ tends to be infinite. That's why I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

Correctly one should find
$$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} (\ln n + \gamma).$$ Next, by L-Hospital $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}=0.$$
Here we have used $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \sim \ln n+\gamma$$

Comment: $\gamma$ is even superfluous.

Comment: Appreciate your answer and I totally agree with you. But what want to figure out is not $\sum\limits^n_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k}$. I will explain why in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As the Harmonic series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac 1k$ diverges, the limit is undefined. (You cannot divide infinity by anything.)